# PHP file not pulling in my .txt's

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have an admin store dashboard with an update button that triggers a php file which empties a mySQL database that then puts in new data from three .txt files (they are new stores). There is an issue where the table just gets wiped and/or the data from the .txt file is not being sent. I recently upgraded my PHP to 5.4 from 5.3 and am unsure what the issue is. Can anyone recommend me a suggestion on how to fix this issue?

[image]

PHP:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
$argv = $_SERVER['argv'];
$totalArgv = count($argv);
// Use PDO to connect to the DB
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=busaweb_stores;host=127.0.0.1';
$dsn_training = 'mysql:dbname=busaweb_busaedu;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'busaweb_*****';
$password = '*****';

try {
$dbs = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
$dbt = new PDO($dsn_training, $user, $password);
$dbs->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
$dbt->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
//echo 'Connected to SQL Server';
} 
catch (PDOException $e) {
die_with_error('PDO Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage());
}

//Check request
if (is_ajax()) {
if (isset($_POST["action"]) && !empty($_POST["action"])) { //Checks if action value exists
$action = $_POST["action"];
switch($action) { //Switch case for value of action
  case "move":
    move_files(); 
    echo_success("Files have been moved.");
    break;
  case "update-stores":
    $count = update_stores_db($dbs);
    echo_success("DB Updated.<br>" . $count . " Stores Geocoded.");
    break;
  case "geocode":
    $count = geocode_remaining($dbs);
    echo_success($count . " stores geocoded.");
    break;
  case "update-training":
    update_training_db($dbt);
    echo_success("Training DB Updated.");
    break;
  case "update-all":
    $count = update_stores_db($dbs);
    update_training_db($dbt);
    echo_success("DB Updated.<br>" . $count . " Stores Geocoded.");
    break;
  case "backup":
    $backupFile = backup_db();
    echo_success("DB Backed Up: <br>" . $backupFile);
    break;
  default:
    //Close PDO Connections
    $dbs = null;
    $dbt = null;
    break;
}
}
}
//if being executed from the shell, update all
else if($totalArgv > 0){
$count = update_stores_db($dbs);
update_training_db($dbt);
echo_success("DB Updated.<br>" . $count . " Stores Geocoded.");
break;
};

//Function to check if the request is an AJAX request
function is_ajax() {
return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest';
}

//Error handling
function die_with_error($error) {
$return = array(
    "status" => "Failed",
    "data" => $error
);
//Close PDO Connections
$dbs = null;
$dbt = null;
die(json_encode($return));
}

function echo_success($message){
$return = array(
    "status" => "OK",
    "data" => $message
);
$return["json"] = json_encode($return);
echo json_encode($return);
//Close PDO Connections
$dbs = null;
$dbt = null;
}

//Move all files
function move_files(){
try {
    move_file('sfinder/StoreList.txt');
    move_file('sfinder/StoreProductIndex.txt');
    move_file('sfinder/StoreTypeIndex.txt');
    move_file('training/TrainingCustomerList.txt');
}
catch(Exception $e){
    die_with_error($e->getMessage());
}

//sleep(1);
//Return JSON
$return["json"] = json_encode($return);
echo json_encode($return);
}

//Move a file
function move_file($filename){
$source ="/home/busaweb/public_html/b3/" . $filename;
$dest = "/home/busaweb/public_html/adminportal/includes/sfupdate/" . $filename;
if(!copy($source, $dest)){
    throw new Exception("Failed to copy file: " . $filename);
}
else{
    //echo "Successfully moved $filename.<br>";
}
}

//Empty a SQL Table
function empty_table($dbconnection, $tablename){
try{
    $sql = "TRUNCATE TABLE " . $tablename;
    $sth = $dbconnection->prepare($sql);
    //$sth->bindParam(':tablename', $tablename, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    // The row is actually inserted here
    $sth->execute();
    //echo " [+]Table '" . $tablename . "' has been emptied.<br>";
    $sth->closeCursor();
}
catch(PDOException $e) {  
    die_with_error($e->getMessage()); 
}
}

//Import CSV file from JDE to DB
function load_csv($dbconn, $filename, $tablename){
try{
    $sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/busaweb/public_html/adminportal/includes/sfupdate/" . $filename . "' INTO TABLE  " . $tablename . " FIELDS TERMINATED BY  '\\t' ENCLOSED BY  '\"' ESCAPED BY  '\\\' LINES TERMINATED BY  '\\n'";
    $sth = $dbconn->prepare($sql);

    // The row is actually inserted here
    $sth->execute();
    //echo " [+]CSV File for '" . $tablename . "' Table Imported.<br>";
    $sth->closeCursor();
}
catch(PDOException $e) {  
    die_with_error($e->getMessage()); 
}
}
function update_stores_db($dbs){
move_files();
empty_table($dbs, "stores");
load_csv($dbs, 'sfinder/StoreList.txt', 'stores');
empty_table($dbs, 'stores_product_type_link');
load_csv($dbs, 'sfinder/StoreProductIndex.txt', 'stores_product_type_link');
empty_table($dbs, 'stores_store_type_link');
load_csv($dbs, 'sfinder/StoreTypeIndex.txt', 'stores_store_type_link');
return $count;
}

function update_training_db($dbt){
move_file('training/TrainingCustomerList.txt');
empty_table($dbt, 'customers');
load_csv($dbt, 'training/TrainingCustomerList.txt', 'customers');
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Till the time you don't get it sorted and see a properly filled txt file why do you even call `empty_table($dbt, 'customers');`

Comment: probably mysql doesn't have the rights to access the `busaweb` user's home directory

Comment: @MarcB how do I give rights? is this a server issue? If it is emptying the database fine, wouldn't it have access to moving the .txt files and/or grabbing it?

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky I agree with you, this is the original PHP file.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: @Fred-ii- http://i.imgur.com/E7ze7fb.png - this is what I am receiving. It seems like this is related to Marc B's comment where the mySQL doesn't have rights to access the home directory, correct?

Comment: well, I for one can't come up with a solution, but at least it's a starting point. Check permissions on the folder?

Comment: you shouldn't be granting mysql rights it doesn't need - it doesn't need access to your website's document tree. Put the .txt files somewhere else, e.g. /tmp, which WILL be accessible by the mysql user.

Comment: @MarcB what do you mean by the document tree? my LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/public_html/adminportal/includes/sfupdate/' is a folder.  you don't mean the $source do you?

Comment: you're doing `load ... /home/x/y/z/p/q/r/`... which means you need to grant the mysql user access to EVERY SINGLE one of those directories. that's not a good idea.

Comment: @MarcB tried to work off this existing code.. my file is located in /adminportal which is in my public_html. the mysql user has all access so i'm not sure why this doesn't work.

Comment: `/adminportal` is a url, which has absolutely no meaning to the underlying file system. mysql runs at the filesystem level, and has no knowledge (and doesn't need any) of how your site's url-space is structured.